# Why does Oracle add a hidden column here?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We recently migrated a customer system to Oracle 12c and to the latest version of our product. This process includes running a number of migration scripts which mostly add or change tables. We noticed that adding a column to a table while also providing a default value, creates an additional hidden column `SYS_NC00002$`.

You should be able to reproduce this with the following code

```
create table xxx (a integer);
alter table xxx add (b integer default 1);

select table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, column_id, default_length, data_default from user_tab_cols where table_name='XXX';

Table_Name|column_Name |data_Type|data_Length|column_Id|default_Length|data_Default|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXX       |A           |NUMBER   |         22|        1|              |            |
XXX       |SYS_NC00002$|RAW      |        126|         |              |            |
XXX       |B           |NUMBER   |         22|        2|             1|1           |
```

When I populate the table and look at the values in that hidden column, they are all the same:

```
select distinct SYS_NC00002$ from xxx;

Sys_Nc00002$|
-------------
01          |
```

Amazingly, when I don't set the default value right away but in an extra statement, no additional hidden column is created.

```
create table xxy (a integer);
alter table xxy add (b integer);
alter table xxy modify b default 1;

select table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, column_id, default_length, data_default from user_tab_cols where table_name='XXY';

Table_Name|column_Name|data_Type|data_Length|column_Id|default_Length|data_Default|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXY       |A          |NUMBER   |         22|        1|              |            |
XXY       |B          |NUMBER   |         22|        2|             1|1           |
```

Can anyone explain what this hidden column is for and why it is only created in the first example, but not in the second?

Comment: btw, I can't reproduce this on 11g

Comment: I just reproduced on 12C.  No idea why though!

Comment: Yes, found this on oracle support https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2277937_1.html

Comment: It's related to DDL optimization. Another useful link.: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/ddl-optimizaton-in-odb12c-2331068.html

Comment: A nice blog that describes the DDL optimization behavior: http://raajeshwaran.blogspot.in/2014/11/ddl-optimization-in-12c.html. It seems that when we set a default value while create or alter the table to add a column with a default value, at that time DDL optimization adds the hidden column. But not when we modify an existing column to have a default value.

Comment: This answers my question and I'd like to give credit to someone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Oracle release 11g Oracle has introdused a new optimization technique for improving the performance of DDL operations. This new feature allows extremely rapid execution time when adding a **NOT NULL** column with default value to an existing table. Since release 12c the DDL optimization has been extended to include **NULL** columns having default value.

Consider following test table with 1.000.000 rows:

```
sql> create table xxy
as select rownum a from dual connect by level <= 1e6
;
sql> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ count(1) from xxy;
sql> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);
```

Now we're going to add an extra not null column having a default value in different sessions for 11g and 12c:

```
11g> alter table xxy add b number default 1;
     --Table XXY altered. Elapsed: 00:01:00.998

12c> alter table xxy add b number default 1;
     --Table XXY altered. Elapsed: 00:00:00.052
```

Notice the difference in the execution time: 1M rows updated in 5 ms !?

Execution plan shows:

```
11g> select count(1) from xxy where b = 1;
  COUNT(1)
----------
   1000000
11g> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |       |       |  1040 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |    13 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| XXY  |   898K|    11M|  1040   (1)| 00:00:13 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - filter("B"=1)
Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)

12c> select count(1) from xxy where b = 1;
12c> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |       |       |   429 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| XXY  |  1000K|  4882K|   429   (2)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - filter(DECODE(TO_CHAR(SYS_OP_VECBIT("SYS_NC00002$",0)),NULL,NVL("
              B",1),'0',NVL("B",1),'1',"B")=1)
Note
-----
   - statistics feedback used for this statement
```

The execution plan on 12c shows by contrast with 11g a complex predicate part involving a new internal column `SYS_NC00006$`.

This predicate indicates that, internally, Oracle is still considering the B column to be potentially able to contain non default values. It means - Oracle at first do not physically updates each row with the default value.

Why a new internal column `SYS_NC00006$` is created?

```
12c> select column_name, virtual_column, hidden_column, user_generated 
from user_tab_cols
where table_name = 'XXY'
;
COLUMN_NAME      VIR HID USE
---------------- --- --- ---
B                NO  NO  YES
SYS_NC00002$     NO  YES NO 
A                NO  NO  YES

12c> select a, b, SYS_NC00002$ hid from xxy where a in (1,10);

        A          B HID            
---------- ---------- ----------------
         1          1                 
        10          1                 

12c> update xxy set b=1 where a=10 and b=1;
1 row updated.

12c> select a, b, SYS_NC00002$ hid from xxy where a in (1,10);
         A          B HID            
---------- ---------- ----------------
         1          1                 
        10          1 01
```

Notice the difference in the values of B and related internal columns. Oracle is simply checking through its system generated internal column (e.g. `SYS_NC00006$`) and via the `SYS_OP_VECBIT` function whether to consider the default value of the B column or the real value modiefed via an explicit DML statement.

What is with two separate alter statements?

```
12c> alter table xxy add (b integer);
12c> alter table xxy modify b default 1;

12c> select count(b), count(coalesce(b,0)) nulls  from xxy where b = 1 or b is null;

  COUNT(B)      NULLS
---------- ----------
         0    1000000
```

The value of new column remains NULL for all rows. No real updates are needed therefore the DDL statement will be not optimized.

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/ddl-optimizaton-in-odb12c-2331068.html) is an OTN article that explains the new DDL optimization in more detail.