# ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, table-partitioning

I ran into the ORA-14097 while exchanging partition. Can anyone share me some light?

I have the following source_tbl (non-partitioned) table and is intended to partition it using the column "VALID_PERIOD_END"

```
CREATE TABLE source_tbl
   (    INVOICE_ID NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    LATEST_FLAG_NAME VARCHAR2(3000), 
    STD_HASH **RAW**(1000), 
    VALID_PERIOD_START TIMESTAMP (6), 
    VALID_PERIOD_END **TIMESTAMP** (6), 
    OVERSEAS NUMBER, 
   .. <another 20 number columns)
    VIP_NO NUMBER
   ) partition by range(VALID_PERIOD_END)
nologging;
```

This table now have 5M rows and I want to partition it by VALID_PERIOD_END so that if it is '9999-12-31 23:59:59' (current) will be in one partition while the rest with be in another partition

I have created a second table called TEMP_tbl

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_tbl
   (    INVOICE_ID NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    LATEST_FLAG_NAME VARCHAR2(3000), 
    STD_HASH **RAW**(1000), 
    VALID_PERIOD_START TIMESTAMP (6), 
    VALID_PERIOD_END **TIMESTAMP** (6), 
    OVERSEAS NUMBER, 
   .. <another 20 number columns)
    VIP_NO NUMBER
   )partition by range(VALID_PERIOD_END)
(partition p1 values less than(maxvalue)) nologging;
```

The TEMP_tbl have exactly the same data structure as source_tbl as the script was driven using
**dbms_metadata.get_ddl**

I have executed gather table status without any error returned

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(USER, upper('source_tbl'), cascade => TRUE);
```

However, when I try to execute the following exchange partition statement, I have the error above

```
alter table TEMP_tbl
          exchange partition p1
          with table source_tbl
          without validation
          update global indexes
;
```

I have checked "user_tab_cols" and I confirm there is no hidden column from the source_tbl. Would it be because of the raw column from my table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is another question on a similar topic.  It isn't exactly a duplicate, but it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684333/partition-exchange-column-type-or-size-mismatch-ora-14097

Comment: @Del, Yes I did notice it and have tried the instruction from the answer. However, I don't have any hidden column. That's why I raised a blog.

Comment: I do see a note in the online documentation about moving a table with a `LONG RAW` column, but nothing on `RAW` or about exchanging partitions with these datatypes.

Comment: As an alternative approach you may consider [`dbms_redefinition`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS74410) package to *add* partitioning to existing table. It also handles the required dependencies by itself.

Comment: Are the sql that you the actual ones (aside from the ***)? because your code for the source_tbl says 'partition by range..'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 12.2 introduced two new partitioning features that will help you a **great** deal here.

1. A new `ALTER TABLE MODIFY PARTITION BY` DDL was introduced that allows conversion of a non-partitioned table to a partitioned table. This operation will copy the data from the existing non-partitioned table into the new table partitions, so it can be long-running. You may specify the `ONLINE` keyword to do the operation in online mode, which means that DML operations on the table will be allowed while the `ALTER TABLE` is running. For example:

```
    ALTER TABLE source_tbl
      MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE(VALID_PERIOD_END)
      (partition p1 values less than (timestamp '9999-12-31 23:59:59'),
       partition p2 values less than (maxvalue))
      ONLINE;
```

2. To help generally with the sort of `EXCHANGE PARTITION` problem you are facing, the `FOR EXCHANGE WITH TABLE` clause was introduced in `CREATE TABLE`. This is specifically intended for matching physical columns exactly when creating a new table that will be exchanged with an existing table. Optionally `FOR EXCHANGE WITH TABLE` can be used along with `PARTITION BY` to create a partitioned table that can be exchanged with the source table. For example:

```
    CREATE TABLE TEMP_tbl
      PARTITION BY RANGE(VALID_PERIOD_END)
      (partition p1 values less than(maxvalue))
      FOR EXCHANGE WITH TABLE source_tbl;
```

[Here is a blog article](https://sqlmaria.com/2017/05/16/extremely-useful-partitioning-enhancements-in-oracle-database-12c/) that describes both of these partitioning enhancements. And [here is another blog article](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/open-for-exchange) that specifically talks using `CREATE TABLE ... FOR EXCHANGE WITH TABLE` to solve `EXCHANGE PARTITION` errors.

You didn't mention which version of Oracle you are using, so perhaps you are still running 11g. In this case you probably need to drill down into `USER_TAB_COLS` to see what the difference is between the two tables. You mentioned that you already checked for hidden columns (which is good) but other mis-matches could occur.

One thing to keep in mind is that `NULLABLE` column attributes must match between the two tables. If one table has primary key constraint and the other one doesn't, the column may be non-nullable in the table with primary key and nullable in the other table, which will cause ORA-14097.

If that doesn't explain the problem you can also check `SEGMENT_COLUMN_ID` ordering, `DATA_TYPE`, `DATA_LENGTH`, `DATA_PRECISION`, and `DATA_PRECISION`. Since you used `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` to create your table these things *should* match, but there must be some difference otherwise you would not get the error.

The `RAW(1000)` column should not be a problem for `EXCHANGE PARTITION`.